# Django: use per-view cache in the URLconf?

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I am using Django 1.8 and I would like to start using Django's filesystem cache, with [a per-view cache in the URLconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache).

This is my `urls.py` right now:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
  '',
  url(r'^api/1.0/spending$',
      'frontend.views.views_api_spending.total_spending_on_substance',
      name='total_spending'),
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
  '',
  url(r'^api/1.0/spending$',
      cache_page(60 * 15)('frontend.views.views_api_spending.total_spending_on_substance'),
      name='total_spending'),
```

But I'm getting an error: `TypeError at /api/1.0/spending: 'str' object is not callable`.

If I remove the quotes, I get: `NameError at /api/1.0/spending: name 'frontend' is not defined`.

How can I adapt my urls file to start using per-view caching?

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to import the `total_spending_on_substance` view function in your `urls.py` and then **pass `total_spending_on_substance` view function to `cache_page` decorator instead of a string**.

`cache_page` is a decorator and it expects a view function. So, wrap the view function `total_spending_on_substance` with cache_page when you are referring to it in the URLconf.

You can do the following:

```
from frontend.views.views_api_spending import total_spending_on_substance # import the view function

urlpatterns = patterns(
  '',
  url(r'^api/1.0/spending$',
      cache_page(60 * 15)(total_spending_on_substance), # pass function instead of string
      name='total_spending'),
```